# Auto scrolling muli-line textfield in compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I've a multi-line text field as below

```
val scrollState = rememberScrollState(0)

TextField(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(75.dp)
        .verticalScroll(scrollState),
    value = caption,
    onValueChange = { onCaptionChanged(it) }
)
```

Currently, it support manual scrolling but i want it to scroll down automatically when user enter new line (\n). How do i achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can scroll using `scrollState.scrollTo`. To track content height change, you can check `scrollState.maxValue`, for example like this:

```
LaunchedEffect(scrollState.maxValue) {
    scrollState.scrollTo(scrollState.maxValue)
    // or 
    // scrollState.animateScrollTo(scrollState.maxValue)
}
```

Comment: Hi @Phil. Any idea to scroll a screen automatically after getting the focus in a TextField? I'm trying here- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77584259/how-to-make-screen-scrollable-on-getting-focus-in-jetpack-compose