# How to auto-scroll to the bottom of a Scrolling Log-Type Text composable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

I'm trying to implement a `Text` view for log-type messages where every change to the text would auto-scroll the Text to the last/newly-added line of text. For example if my text size only fits 4 lines:

```
log 1
log 2
log 3
log 4
```

and a new line is added, then the output should be:

```
log 2
log 3
log 4
log 5
```

The specific problem I'd like to find a solution for is how to scroll down to the bottom every time there's a change in the text value.  I tried the accepted solution for [`TextField`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70572879/390718), where a `LaunchedEffect` is triggered during composition phase, but it didn't work in my case:

```
@Composable
fun LogText(log: State<String>) {

  var logState = rememberScrollState(0)
  val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

  LaunchedEffect(coroutineScope) {
      logState.scrollTo(logState.maxValue)
  }

  Text(
      text = log.value,
      modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(logState),
  )
}
```

The `LaunchedEffect` did not change the Text to scroll down to the newest line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your usage of `LaunchedEffect` is wrong. The lambda you are passing to the `LaunchedEffect` is executed every time the `LaunchedEffect`'s key(s) are changed. You are using remembered coroutine scope as a key, which never changes, therefore your effect is only executed once.

Also, the `LaunchedEffect` lambda is launched in coroutine scope by default, so you don't need your own.

Try it like this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun LogText(log: State<String>) {

  var logState = rememberScrollState(0)

  LaunchedEffect(log.value) {
      logState.scrollTo(logState.maxValue)
  }

  ...
}
```

this means: everytime the `log.value` changes, execute the lambda.

And one more thing: if your text gets really long, drawing it like that will be quite heavy. I would consider splitting it by lines to `List<String>` and using `LazyColumn` with multiple `Text` items...