# How to make screen scrollable on getting focus in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to add autoscroll to the screen as it gets focus on `TextField` as

```
Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                      .padding(bottom = 2.dp)
                      .alpha(loadingAlpha)
                      .background(Color.White)
                      .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState(), true),
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally, ) {
  TextField(modifier =
                modifier.fillMaxHeight()
                    .weight(0.75f)
                    .clickable() {
                      coroutineScope.launch {
                        scrollState.animateScrollTo(
                            scrollToPosition.roundToInt())
                      }
                    })
}
```

Currently `TextFields` get hidden when keypad gets opened. So I'm trying to make the auto scroll upwards when any `TextField` gets focus.

I've mentioned `adjustResize` for `android:windowSoftInputMode` in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Did you try change `android:windowSoftInputMode` in your `manifest.xml` ?

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention that I'm using `adjustResize` in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Try applying `imePadding` modifier to the `TextField` or `safeDrawingPadding` modifier to the `Column`.

Comment: It didn't help @JanItor

Comment: It would help to see the whole layout, but I guess it is because of the `weight` or `fillMaxHeight` mods on the `TextField`. They don't seem really necessary to achieve your layout, could it work without them? @AnshulTyagi